# Correct pattern to hold a reference to a DOM element in Knockout JS

Tags: javascript, dom, knockout.js

I understand it's a bad practice to handle DOM stuff in a Knockout model. But what would be the correct pattern to hold a reference to an element in a model?

Say I have a model for a menu:

```
MenuModel = function()
{
    var self = this;
    self.buttons = [{ text: "set color" }, { text: "set border" }];
};
```

Now, this menu represents a DOM element and each button in the menu manipulates the DOM of the represented element.

Would this be a correct pattern to store the element reference?

```
MenuModel = function(el)
{
    var self = this;
    self.element = el;
    self.buttons = [{ text: "set color" }, { text: "set border" }];
};
```

So when a menu button is clicked, the parent model (MenuModel) for the button holds the reference to the element.

I understand that a solution would be to provide a Knockout model for the represented element and change that model so the element changes based on the model changes. But It's not practical for me, at this point I really need to alter the element DOM directly.

Comment: What change do you need to make to the element as the model changes?

Comment: Two way [data binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-syntax.html) with binding handlers and [observables](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html) are the proper way to keep your view model and view in sync. 

Knockout comes with a rich set of binding handlers.  If the built in ones are not adequate you can always make a [custom binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html).

Answer (score 3):

Why would you want to hold a reference of the DOM element in your JS? I think this is rather an anti-pattern. Have a look at this [MVVM graphic from Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel#/media/File:MVVMPattern.png). Clearly your `MenuModel` is not really a model, but rather a `viewModel`; it holds no data, it only holds presentation logic. The models would be the JSON/XML data you're getting from the backend, and eventually transform through constructor functions into named object instances. The flow between viewModel (JS) and view (HTML) is bound through `data-binding`. If you stick to the pattern Knockout advocates, you should keep it as simple as this:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: buttons">
  <li data-bind="text: text"></li>
</ul>
```

You can simply add an action property to each button object, and pass the parameters `yourFunction(data, e)` to manipulate your view like in the snippet below. If you need to access other elements than those in the view's hierarchy, you can always stick a class/ id to it, then reference its data with `ko.dataFor(elem)` or `ko.contextFor(elem)`.

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: buttons">
  <li data-bind="text: text, click: action"></li>
</ul>
```

For performance/ code readability, you might prefer not to attach an event binding to every element (especially in a list). In that case, please refer to either Knockout's section on [unobtrusive event handling](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/unobtrusive-event-handling.html) or another solution like R.Niemeyer's plugin [Knockout delegated events](https://github.com/rniemeyer/knockout-delegatedEvents).

So to answer `But what would be the correct pattern to hold a reference to an element in a model?` - I would say, none. In all Knockout code I've written, I can't think of a single case where this was required. If this doesn't convince, have a read at [What is separation of concerns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98734/what-is-separation-of-concerns) and [loose coupling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loose_coupling).

Comment: Your answer makes sense. The `MenuModel` should maybe be named `MenuViewModel` since it only holds presentation logic, but how does the action in `click:action` know which element it should manipulate if no reference to that element?

Comment: Actually you should get a reference with the event object that should be passed to your handler. So in your "action" function, try this: `function action (event) { var target = event.target; ...`

Comment: @frontend_dev The event is actually the second argument to the handler.  The first argument is the data it's bound to.  See "Note 2" of http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html.

Comment: Yes you're right. So do it like this: `function action (data, event)`

Comment: @frontend_dev Yes, but that would give me a reference to the clicked menu button. The question of the post was how to pass a reference to an element that the menu represents, but that isn't in the same hierarchical DOM structure as the menu or the menu button.

Comment: @Adrian what do you need to modify on the element when the button is clicked?  If you can update the question with what you are trying to accomplish we can give you a better answer.

Comment: @AdrianRosca Then you'd simply give the referenced element a class or ID , and in your click binding, access the element's data like so `ko.dataFor(document.getElementById('myelem')).objProperty`. I'll edit my answer in a few hours (no time now) to contain this piece of info